# Angular-formly. SetType options

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-formly

When i am creating a new type with setType in angular-formly how do i display options in the template.

I want a type named category that displays the label on the webpage, so how do i gwt the label name?

My code so far:

```
//new type for adding a category label
formlyConfig.setType([
      {
            name:'category',
            template: '<div><center><b>"options.label"</b></center></div>'
      }
]);
```

Print is the variable i want to display on the page, formlyField is the formly array.

```
formlyField.push(
     {
            type: 'category',
            templateOptions: {
                label: print
            }

     }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
//new type for adding a category label
formlyConfig.setType([
      {
            name:'category',
            template: '<div><center><b>{{options.label}}</b></center></div>'
      }
]);
```

and for your fields

```
formlyField.push(
     {
            type: 'category',
            templateOptions: {
                label: 'print'
            }

     }
);
```